# URL Redirect doesn't seem to be working

Tags: php, .htaccess

so I'm working on this project where I need to make a referral module.
I have to rewrite the URL in such a way, that the page **refer_handler.php?refhash=(base64encode(email))** re-writes to **/refer/(base64encode(email))**

I have this code for the redirect :-

```
RewriteRule ^refer/(\d+)$ refer_handler.php?refhash=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Here's the refer_handler.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'dbconnector.php';
include 'inc/inc.functions.php';
include 'dbpdo.php';
if((isset($_SESSION['logged'])) && ($_SESSION['logged']=1))
{
    //get the email id from the header
    $emailOfTheReferrer = $_REQUEST['refhash']; // we get the refhash from here.
    echo base64_decode($emailOfTheReferrer);
    ////////////////
    //Layers -- // 
    //Check if the refer hash exists  (Check if the parent email exists)
}
else
{
    header('Location:../index');
}
?>
```

**Problem**

The URL re-writes doesn't seems to be working.
When I go to /refer/somerefhash , it says :- Not Found.
But, if I use the same refhash and then user the URL refer_handler.php?refhash=thehashhere
Then everything seems to be working fine.

How can I fix this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `(\d+)` only allows digits. And `base64` encoded string may contain other characters.

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^refer/(.+)$ refer_handler.php?refhash=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This captures 1 or more of **any** characters instead.